# Make field larger so more text displays

Tags: lightning

I have a recordEditForm for adding new records.  In that form I have inputfields.  One of the fields is for a description and that tends to get long.  Any way to make the field display more real estate?  I am using formatting to make the box bigger but unsure of how to make the text that displays show more.

Here is my field:

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-Small" > 
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description__c" value="{!v.groupstructure.Description__c}"/>
               </lightning:layoutItem>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: your top level component (layoutItem) is setting a certain size to the component,  and your lightning:inputField doesnt seemt o have any calss indicating it shoudl fill in the parent container. How, and what exactly is it that you are trying to achieve, mayeb sharing a screenshot fo the current and expected behavior will help others provide better feedback on what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I just added a picture of what I have now.  I would like that description field to take  more vertical real estate (3 or 4 lines)  thanks again!!!!

Comment: But these are custom components so I'm  not sure what you mean by "create your own custom components"  I will say that IMO, the new lighting display is horrible.  Its so hard to focus and everything is washed together.

Comment: BTW - I was able to do what I needed by changing inputField to textarea.  that gave me more real estate.  But I really would appreciate your input on how you would go about making the styling look better.  As I said, if you don't style it, all the fields blend together.  thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying don't use lightning:inputField?  I'm new to Javascript so this has been a challenge.  I finally have everything working using the recordEditForm  If you could give me a little more direction I would really appreciate it. thanks!!!!!!

Comment: your post is confusing - not sure what you need - yes, a text area will provide more space, however, this is bound to the field type which is set at an object leve, not in the ui

Comment: Thanks.  I’m sorry I made it confusing.  I was simply trying to expose more space so the user can see what they are typing.  Thanks again

Comment: in that case, as you noticed, changing the field type will give you this flexibility.

Comment: Thanks again!  I am just a little concerned about your comment on my use omg Css.  Is there another option to make text stand out other than what I am doing which is creating my own style classes and applying them to different areas of the page.  Thanks!

Comment: ignore that comment - ill remove it =) haha